# How to go to a specific time on Bilibili embed video

Tags: javascript, video, iframe, embed

I have embedded a video from BiliBili on my webpage like below.
(BiliBili is a Youtube type of video platform in China)

```
<iframe id="player" src="//player.bilibili.com/player.html?aid=373664867&bvid=BV1no4y1o7kd&cid=282712597&page=1&high_quality=1&danmaku=0&as_wide=1" 
                     scrolling="no" border="0" frameborder="no" framespacing="0"> 
</iframe>
```

I wonder if I can move to a specific time by handling events.
for example, if I click some button, it listens to this click event and takes me to a specific time which is like Youtube iframe api has.

```
player.seekTo(10)
```

It is hard to find any document or even code snippet about BiliBili in English.
Please if anyone knows this, help me!

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, it works just like Youtube.
you add "t=(second)", at the end of the link
then you're good to go!
for example,
https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1uT4y1P7CX? this video
to go to 00:43 , type:
https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1uT4y1P7CX?t=43

Comment: We want to do it programmatically, and not directly with link